# Is it possible that a primary key is not autoincrement?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, auto-increment

I am trying to insert an element in a table where there are already 3 rows.

Its a table called ***usuarios***=[**id** (primary, autoincrement), **fid**, **first_name**, **last_name..**..]

So there are already 3 rows with id's: **0,1,2**

And when I am trying to execute this query (note I am not setting value for id attribute)

```
INSERT INTO usuarios (fid,email,pass,first_name,last_name,avatar,bday,fecha,id_loc,id_loc_from) 
       VALUES       (-1,'toni@ideadeia.com','72253f579e7dc003da754dad4bd403a6','','','',NOW(),NOW(),'','')
```

I get this mysql error:

```
Duplicate entry '0' for key 1
```

extra: I don't know how this 3 items where inserted (if via interface, by console query, ..)

So question is, how can I make sure that the `Primary Key`is autoincrement, and if not; how to set it? (will that solve the problem?)

Comment: there are no other keys than the primary..

Comment: Can you provide the actual table schema for this table?

Comment: ah, yea there are all sorts of primary keys. Maybe the seed was reset on this table? so it thinks the next auto-increment id should be zero...

Comment: That's what I was going to say. This sql command resets the initial value: ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 0;

Comment: i did a sql export of the table and its not autoincrement. so now i need to know how to set id as auto_increment = 3, David Stratton posted an answer, but its returning errors..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to set it as auto-increment using this statement if you have rights to alter the table:

```
ALTER TABLE usuarios  modify id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Although I've seen reports of bugs that recommend instead dropping the colulmn and recreating it, if the above doesn't work for some reason. the syntax recommended in those posts is:

```
ALTER TABLE usuarios  
         DROP COLUMN id;

ALTER TABLE usuarios  
         ADD COLUMN idINT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST;
```

**Warning:** Do this in a test database first.  You'd want to be careful doing this if the table is using this as a foreign key. It could fail at best, or break all the relationships at worst.

There's tons of info at the [MySql reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Comment: If you want to start from 3, then add "= 3" after AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: (first query) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 3' at line 1 ___ any idea why? i am using the root user

Comment: I think the "=3" was incorrect.  I added it because of Jeremy Goodell's note.  I don't have a MySql database where I'm at right now to test it on, but according to the documentation I've been readin the the "=3" is ***not*** correct in that statement.  If I'm not mistaken, you would use the first statement above FOLLOWED BY ALTER TABLE usuarios  AUTO_INCREMENT = 2;  That resets the increment onteh table to the CURRENT value of 2 so the NEXT record inserted will be 3.  Sorry, my strength is SQL Server.  I'm learning up on MySql in my spare time, so I'm pretty weak.  I'm learning as I go.

Comment: If the corrections in the note above work, credit goes to this article: http://www.ehow.com/how_8504844_mysql-insert-auto-increments.html